# How do I handle the where conditions dynamically in squeel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, squeel

From this input: {'hearing' => 1} I need to generate this query

```
Score.joins(:target_disability).where{ (target_disabilities.name == 'hearing') & (round(total_score) >= 1) }
```

From this input is {'hearing' => 1, 'mobility' => 2}, I need to generate this:

```
Score.joins(:target_disability).where{ (target_disabilities.name == 'hearing') & (round(total_score) >= 1) | (target_disabilities.name == 'mobility') & (round(total_score) >= 2) }
```

And so on...

How can this be generalized? Because my input sometimes has 3 or 4 keys... sometime 1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your hash is in `my_params`:

```
@scores = Score.joins(:target_disability).where do
    my_params.map{|k,v| (target_disabilities.name==k) & (round(total_score)>=v) }.inject(:|)
end
```

Comment: can you look at this for me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654010/squeel-and-rails-dynamic-where-clause