# Squeel and rails... dynamic where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, squeel

Using Squeel, in a rails app, I have a hash of conditions:

```
{'trans' => 'manual'}
```

which i eventually plan on moving into an array... so i can also have an operator assignment.

```
[[field,operator,value][field,operator,value]]
```

I want to use a Model method, which for now i omit the operator and am I just trying == to get this to work... however, what i have below does not work.

```
def self.with_conditions(conditions)
    joins{car}.where do
      conditions.map {|key,value| (key==value) }.inject(:&)
    end
end
```

I also tried this:

```
def self.with_conditions(conditions)
  joins{car}.where do
    query = nil

    conditions.each do |key, value|
      q = (key == value)

      if query
        query &= q
      else
        query = q
      end
    end

    query     
  end
end
```

So, how do i get this to work with the ==, and then how would i eventually get this to work with a dynamic operator as well? thanks

In console, my SQL doesn't read in any of my conditions... for example:

in console:

```
> Timeslip.with_conditions({'car.year'=>'1991'})

SELECT "timeslips".* FROM "timeslips" INNER JOIN "cars" ON "cars"."id" = "timeslips"."car_id"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to programmatically build the Squeel query. For example:

```
def self.with_conditions(conditions)
  conditions.map do |col, str|
    Squeel::Nodes::Predicate.new(Squeel::Nodes::Stub.new(col), :matches, str) # (email.matches "user@example.com")
  end.inject do |t, expr|
    t & expr # joins each expression from the .map above with & - to be converted to AND in the sql
  end.tap do |block|
    return where{(block)} # pass the constructed expression to Squeel
  end
end
```

On my `User::User` model I can run

```
User::User.with_conditions({email: "user@example.com", first_name: "Deefour"}).to_sql
```

and I will get

```
SELECT "user_users".* FROM "user_users"  WHERE (("user_users"."email" LIKE 'user@example.com' AND "user_users"."first_name" LIKE 'Deefour'))
```

Comment: So this doesn't really seem less complicated than just using Arel? Do you agree? Any tips on using a dynamic operator, to replace :matches  as well?

Comment: `:matches` is just a symbol corresponding to a Squeel method. You can pass that in with the `conditions` - maybe passing in an Array of Hashes like `[{ col: :first_name, query: "Deefour", method: :matches }]`

Comment: Ok, so i have this almost working, but i need to be able to use an association name which would be dynamic as well. How would i go about passing in the association name to the above code? I think this is gonna work for me! thanks for your help!

Comment: I will try to spend some time on this, but it looks like I will have to review the docs a bit more.

Comment: I am getting closer.... `def self.conditions(tables, conditions)
    table_name = Squeel::Nodes::Stub.new(tables[0].to_sym)
    joins(table_name)
    .where {
      table_name.send(conditions[0]).eq(conditions[1])
    }
  end` for now i am just using direct calls to the array, but this code is a 50% working solution. I'm still having trouble getting it all to work though with the dynamic variables

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but I did it this way using this helper method:

```
  def query_for_matches(key, value)
    stub = Squeel::Nodes::Stub.new(key)
    Squeel::Nodes::Predicate.new(stub, :matches, "%#{value}%")
  end
```

You have a hash of parameters from a request of something:

```
  dynamic_params = {'username' => 'some_name', 'email' => 'email@example.com'}
```

Then I use this with a chain of `where`'s in a loop:

```
  query = SomeModel #could be User, etc
  dynamic_params.each_pair {|key,value| query = query.where(query_for_matches(key, value)) }
```

You can then pass `query` to your view or whatever.  I've only been on rails for a couple of weeks so I'm not sure if this is a *best practice* but it works.