# route for username to go to a profile#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a User model, where users have a username, and User has_one :profile

I want to make a route so that if a person goes to "http://www.website.com/username" it goes to profile#show.

at the bottom of my routes, i have:

```
match ":username" => "profiles#show"
```

But, it's not finding the ID of the profile, which I expected.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProfilesController#show
Couldn't find Profile without an ID
```

I just am not sure how to properly make the route so i get the id of the user from the :username

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `:username` in `params`. You need to find the `Profile` based on the associated `User` model's `:username`. In your action:

```
@profile = User.find_by_username(params[:username]).profile
```

Comment: you rock, sir! Can you take a look at my last comment on your answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654010/squeel-and-rails-dynamic-where-clause